# Get invitation letter and then find a place to rent

Tags: student-visa, spain, internship

We are making an invitation letter for a friend (from Tunisia) to stay with us (in Spain) while she works as an intern. We already have the invitation letter from the company, but we still lack one of the requirements for the student visa (more than 90 days), which is a place to stay. For the moment, she's gonna stay with us. But if she's able to afford it, and get a place of her own during her stay, would that be possible? Do we have to notify the police department? Because the invitation letter states she's gonna stay with us for that period, what kind of problems might we have?

Answer (score 0):

The problems you would have are, if they catch you, then they might mark you for misrepresentation, and then you would have trouble getting future documents.  However, you can specify that she plans to move as soon as reasonable -- and then you would avoid this kind of problem, and also avoid the need to report to the authorities when that happens.